# GmailV1/GmailService get_user_messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api, gmail, gmail-api, google-api-ruby-client

[google-api-ruby-client doc](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google/Apis/GmailV1/GmailService#list_user_messages-instance_method)

I am wondering why function get_user_messages only has 1 parameter user_id even though in doc, they have more than that.

I'm using this version:

> gem install google-api-client -v '~> 0.8'

```
 message = gmail.list_user_messages(user_id, false)
```

When i tried to put value of optional parameters, error occurred

> wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1) (ArgumentError)

Thanks

Comment: Which version of the api client is actually installed?

Comment: google-api-client-0.24.2

Answer (score 1):

The response for [Messages.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) has one required parameters that being user id.  The rest are optional parameters.  These can be added to your request as well.

You can see the option parms in your library [list_user_messages-instance_method](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google/Apis/GmailV1/GmailService#list_user_messages-instance_method)

```
result = gmail.get_user_message('me', id)
```

I would guess that you could do to include trash.

```
result = gmail.get_user_message('me', id, true)
```

Note: I am not a ruby dev.

**Response info.**

The response for [Messages.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) is as follows

```
 "messages": [
  {
   "id": "16641115eca503dc",
   "threadId": "16641115eca503dc"
  },
```

There is no way of getting it to return more information.  At one point it did but not even sending fields = * will return more information.

If you want more information about a message you will need to do a [messages.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get)

Comment: Sorry for my short question which made you misunderstand, I just made it more clearly a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

I found out my problem.

Change:

> message = gmail.list_user_messages(user_id, false)

To

> message = gmail.list_user_messages(user_id, include_spam_trash: false)

I got a basic syntax error of ruby.